# Directories aren't on the beginning of the view in Nautilus file manager, how to change this?

Tags: nautilus, files, directory, sort

[image: the view of wordpress directory as an example]

I am on Ubuntu 19.04. I have probably clicked some shortcut which changed directory view in Nautilus (Files application) and for a few days all directories are sorted like on the screenshot.

I can't find any option "directories first", is it possible to switch the view to the desired (when directories are always at the beginning of a window and then are files)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First open *Files* (Nautilus) preferences by clicking "Files" next to the "*Activities*" button at the top left (when you have a Files window in focus) and selecting '*Preferences*'. Alternatively, if the top bar application menu is disabled in your system, you would be able to access the preferences from the hamburger menu (three horizontal bars menu) of a Files window.

Then in the preferences window, under '*View*' tab, you should find a "*sort folders before files*" option.

Comment: thank you, that's it except small difference: it was not in this menu on top of the screen but it was inside file manager window, on its bar, on the right, that hamburger menu, this is where I found Preferences (gosh, how bad is this UX/UI so I have to describe it like this instead telling the name of this button - when I hover buttons, nothing shows)

Comment: @kkarpieszuk Thanks for the info, I have updated the answer accordingly.